# HTML5 canvas drawImage function slow when source and destination canvases are same?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

I noticed that the drawImage function is 1000+ times slower when both source and destination canvases are the same. Why is this ? What canvases go to the GPU and what don't ?
Any help on this topic would be very much appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Most canvas implementation will use weGL / Open GL behind the scene.  
Using the canvas as both a source and destination will require to copy the whole screen before the operation, which is a somehow slow operation... very badly handled by the browsers (a copy is not required if the rects do not overlap, yet performances shows the copy is done).

Answer (score 2):

When you use the canvas as both source and destination, the browser is required to do (there are finer steps involved, but these are the main ones):

- Create a scratch bitmap to copy to
- Copy current bitmap into scratch bitmap
- Copy scratch bitmap back to original bitmap at a different position (ie. drawImage(canvas,...));
- Remove scratch

This instead of when you use separate canvases:

- Copy source bitmap to destination bitmap

Why not just "blitting"? The **[official standard define](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage)** this case in this way (my emphasis):

> When a canvas or CanvasRenderingContext2D object is **drawn onto itself**,
>   the drawing model **requires** the source to be copied before the image is
>   drawn, so it is possible to copy parts of a canvas or scratch bitmap
>   onto overlapping parts of itself.

Also take a look at the **[Drawing Model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#drawing-model)** for the steps involved.